# file name matching, differentiation with numbers and characters

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell, match

I have a folder with many files, 
the name of some files are like file_1 file_10 file_21  file_345
others are like file_fr file_de file_cn
I want to move the first type of files into another folder
like

```
mv file_* another_folder
```

but file_* will match all files

are there any good scripts?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
mv file_[0-9]* another_folder
```

In response to [**glenn jackman’s comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207015/file-name-matching-differentiation-with-numbers-and-characters/14207051#comment19703602_14207051)

```
ls | grep 'file_[0-9]*$' | xargs mv -t another_folder
```

Comment: This pattern means a digit followed by zero or more of any character. If the OP's files are as strictly separated as he says, this is file. If there's a `file_1foo`, it will be moved. The OP has to decide if this is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

bash:

```
shopt -s extglob
mv file_+([0-9]) ..
```

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching